# Is there a useful pattern for managing "quantum state changes" for events? (specfically in JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, events, observer-pattern

There are all kinds of ways to respond to events singularly. However I am running into the phenomenon repeatedly where I want to change several properties and then respond to the state after all changes have been made.

The classic case - I have a datagrid that has transactions for an account. When I change from one account to the other, I also change the date range and the sort key / order. This is three properties(accountID, sorting, dateRange), but I don't want to trigger three change events independently -- at least, not when I switch accounts. However, these states do have underlying watchers, for when the last two states change, from user interaction.

Is there any intelligent way to manage quantum changes of parameters, separately from individual changes in parameters? You can always have a global state_is_changing property to neutralize events as you change events one by one, but then when you "unhook" the state_is_changing property you then have to either re-poll your state from a higher level or have event effects "queued up" that were triggered during the period of change.

Neither of these solutions seem elegant.

Does anyone know of a design pattern wherein you can manage tactical and quantum state change within an event system elegantly?

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged this with the Observer pattern, but it sounds like what you want is the Mediator pattern... which listens to various sources and provides higher level logic.

Give this a read and see if it suits what you're thinking: http://addyosmani.com/largescalejavascript/#mediatorpattern